# Not sure how to add image variance to php/sql population of HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

### Situation

I am currently populating an HTML table using PHP, which is working just fine using this code:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $lineID             = $row['lineID'];
    $ediShipDate        = $row['ediShipDate'];
    $resolution         = $row['resolution'];
    $resolutionComments = $row['resolutionComments'];

?>
```

### Issue

I am trying to make it so with each individual line, if ediShipDate equals one thing, I place one image there (instead of the text inside that variable), and if it equals another thing, to place a different image.  I'm trying using this code in the middle here:

```
<td>
          <?= $cost?>
          <value="<?= $cost?>"></td>
<td>
          <?php 
            if ($row['ediShipDate'] = "Before Debit Exp"){
              print("<img src=/img/check-yes.png>");
              print("one") ;
            }
            else if  ($row['ediShipDate'] = "AFTER DEBIT EXP!"){
              print("<img src=/img/check-no.png>");
              print("two") ;
            }
            else {
            print $row['ediShipDate'] ;
            print("three") ;
            }
          ?>
          <value="<?= $ediShipDate ?>"></td>
<td>
              <?= $cost?>
              <value="<?= $cost?>"></td>
```

With my test data, I have 4 rows.  The first three's value is "Before Debit Exp" while the fourth's value is "AFTER DEBIT EXP!", however, in the debug code I have here `print("one")` etc..., all four rows are evaluating to the first statement, regardless of their value, and printing out `check-yes.png`  I've tried changing all of them to have the actual value of "AFTER DEBIT EXP!" to no avail.

Why is this?  There is nothing in the logs or the console.

Answer (score 2):

In your IF statement you're assigning the value not comparing.

`=` vs `==` or `===`

You need to switch them to `==` at the very least, but it would be better to use `===`.

```
          <?php 
            if ($row['ediShipDate'] === "Before Debit Exp"){
              print("<img src=/img/check-yes.png>");
              print("one") ;
            }
            else if  ($row['ediShipDate'] === "AFTER DEBIT EXP!"){
              print("<img src=/img/check-no.png>");
              print("two") ;
            }
            else {
            print $row['ediShipDate'] ;
            print("three") ;
            }
          ?>
          <value="<?= $ediShipDate ?>"></td>
```